# What can users can do about disagreeable review audits?

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits

I just ran into a review audit which was obviously an audit, but I intentionally failed it because I disagree with it. Something just seems wrong about flagging or skipping a question that I think has been wrongly closed.

Does a certain number of users failing an audit prevent the system from reusing it? Is there a better way to handle review audits that we disagree with? Am I just shooting myself in the foot by trying to do the right thing?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi It's a similar question, but that provides none of the answers that I'm looking for. I've thoroughly read that question and all of its comments several times, including right before asking this question.

Comment: True ;) But the previous questioner is in the same situation as yours, there are helpful comments there, and working on a single, canonical question regarding audit disputes seems the right way to go.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Although there are helpful comments there, they are not helpful to my question. If that question or its comments answered what I'm asking, I wouldn't be asking. I even still had that question open in another tab when you linked it.

Comment: I won't call it a *terrible* question, but it certainly was not even a good or mediocre question.  It showed no effort, and was, IMHO, entirely justified as being closed as "Too broad".  `Whether you agree or disagree with me doesn't matter for my question though.`  Eh, I'm letting my comment stand :)

Comment: If you know it's an audit, and you disagree with the audit, then don't be afraid to _skip the audit_ as that does not count against you. If you want that audit to be removed, there is a way. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168374/bring-a-human-factor-into-review-audit-composition-selection

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Sure it's not a great question. But on the other hand, I've seen other questions ask the same thing, but phrased differently, for other platforms, and they've been received well. The equivalent Android question has 17 upvotes, 0 downvotes, 4 answers, and 25 favorites as of now.

Comment: @Brian - but when was it asked?  Got a link?  Based on the number of upvotes and favorites, I'm betting it was asked quite a while back, when things were less regulated/defined.  I could be wrong, though.

Comment: Also, this just goes to show a problem with trying to programatically dispute audits; a person may *think* they've received a bad audit, when in reality, they're not reviewing properly.  Better to raise the issue here in Meta and get feedback, I think.

Comment: Maybe we should have a `[specific-audit]` tag... naw, just kidding.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables True, it is an older question. I'd link, but I've seen a certain negative mentality toward questions linked from meta. Someone flags or makes a negative comment, and people downvote without reading (which is already happening to this question) and then people start downvoting linked questions or answers. I'd rather not subject someone else's perfectly good question to that. I hate saying that that happens here, but I've seen it too many times

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables I was originally planning to raise it here, and then I realized that we can't have every user posting every review audit they disagree with as a question on meta. There are also a few comments on other questions that say the same thing.

Comment: Should I remove the specific example from my question? I think it might just be distracting from the real question.

Comment: Please don't feed the help vampires.

Comment: @Will The help vampires?

Comment: @Brian gnat's comment did not cause it to be closed.  He cast the 4th close vote, proposing a different duplicate the original one.  The 5th closer voter caused it to be closed.  And the answer in that question tells you exactly how to dispute a review audit.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I'm not asking how to dispute a review audit.

Comment: @Brian, then I'm afraid *that's not clear at all* from your question. You should consider editing your title and your last paragraph to reflect that.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi My question is hard to phrase differently enough that the people who only read only pieces of it will understand the difference, and still keep it short enough that they don't skip the body entirely. I'll give an example (see next comment, not enough room in this one).

Comment: I'm doing reviews, and come across one created by a username that's just "user" and some numbers, with no link. The system says that this is probably spam. Trying to open the question in another tab to see if it has any answer shows that the content has been deleted. I carefully read the question, and decide that either it shouldn't have been deleted, or it could go either way, making it a bad audit question. I cannot pass this audit without lying, skipping it leaves it as a trap for other reviewers, and failing the review counts against me. What do I do?

Comment: @Brian, so, you don't want to pass the audit, you don't want to skip it, you don't want to fail it and you just mentioned you also don't want to dispute it. I'm afraid we're out of options. Unless you suggest we get rid of the audit system altogether, but then Patricia's strategy would scale better.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Right, those are the only three options. So I'm looking for what to do when all three of those options are bad. I'm also asking what I can do to prevent such questions from being used for audits in the future, since none of those three options achieves that.

Comment: @Brian do you understand the purpose of review audits.  They aren't really there to test your understanding of the system or educate.  They are there to catch people who robotically click "Looks OK" or something else in an effort to game the system to get a badge.  The simply fact that you recognized the review as audit means you passed.  So you can do whatever you want to skip or pass the audit and not feel bad about yourself.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Thanks, that answers part of my question. I think "skip it and don't worry about it" probably is the best option. I'm still wondering what the best way to suggest that it not be used for audits is though. It sounds like posting to meta is the only option, but is also a generally unfavorable option.

Comment: @Brian you go to the post and do the opposite of what the audit wanted (which is what gnat duplicate question says).... so you downvote and/or flag a post that the audit says is good, you upvote one that it says is bad.  If you are in the close vote queue, you vote to close a post that the audit thinks is good.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Oh, that's why he linked that, I didn't think to read the answer because the question is only vaguely related. That solution works for content that the system thinks is good, but not if the content has been deleted (unless the user has > 20k rep). I hope this oversight is eventually addressed. I think all of my questions have been answered at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL/DR: Bring it up on meta.**

First, the review audits are to keep people from going on autopilot and actually doing their jobs as reviewers.  The questions that come up as audits *should* belong unambiguously in one category or another (in this case it should be obvious that it should either be closed or left open).  It seems like there is always an occasional post on meta about "I failed an audit. Why?" or something similar.  And those posts get useful feed back, which is what it seems like you need.

### Scenario 1: The Question Really Deserves to Be Closed.

Ok, you disagree that a question should be closed, but the community does not.  Posting on meta allows people to help explain why they feel it should be closed.  Maybe the community is making different assumptions than you are?  Maybe you are looking at old questions as evidence that this one should stand when those old (and open) questions don't reflect current policy?  There are way to many "maybe" reasons as to why your opinion may be different than the community's and if you really are wrong, meta can help get you straightened out.

### Scenario 2: The Review Audit is Just Plain Wrong

Sometimes the audit question selector thing just screws up.  Posting on meta lets people see it and evaluate.  If it really is bad, someone at SO can see so and get it fixed.

### Scenario 3: It's in a Gray Area and I Don't Agree With The Decision Made

If it exists in that nebulous land where it isn't clear cut what should be done, first it probably doesn't belong in the bucket of audit questions.  Post here so it can be removed if necessary.  Posting also allows for discussion of what should be done with such a question.  Is it really off-topic? Why? On-topic? Why? Does policy need changing? Better wording for the close reason / help center?  Through the discussion we can reach a concensus and do something about it.

Finally, purposely failing the audit doesn't help anything.  Failing it to make a point is wasted effort because the machine on the other end won't notice or care.  It only hurts you at that point.  Bring it up here where those who care and can do something about it can help.

Comment: `TL/DR: Bring it up on meta.` we don't need a new post every time someone disagrees with an audit.  The methods for forcing the system to not use a post as an audit again are well documented.

Comment: "Failing it to make a point is wasted effort because the machine on the other end won't notice or care." So yes, I am just shooting myself in the foot. Oh well, I knew it was a likely possibility. I like your answer overall, but I think having every user post a meta question for every review audit that they disagree with is excessive.

Comment: As for the audit that spurred this question, I would put that in scenario 3. I don't feel that it's a good enough question to push to reopen, but I think it's in a gray area, which makes it a poor example to use for audits.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Honest question: where are these documented?  I've never seen it so I'm curious what makes that thing tick and how you would make it not use a question again.

Comment: @psubsee2003 If we don't have people bring up their confusion on meta (or at least poke around and hopefully find an answer) what should we have them do?  I would rather not have confused or misguided reviewers out there.  Meta (or maybe chat) seems like the best place to be able to ask for clarification or help.

Comment: @Becuzz they are littered around numerous similar questions to yours.  Most are probably on [MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/) for legacy reasons (it used to be Meta.StackOverflow).  But the short version is exactly what is in gnat's proposed duplicate.

Comment: @Becuzz asking for clarification on meta (such as, "why is this a good post") is fine after doing research,  Just bringing it up on meta simply because you disagree is not productive.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extremely simple and effective solution to disagreements with the audits - stop reviewing.

If everyone who thought the current audit system has problems did this, there would be one of two outcomes:

1. There would be enough people left who are happy with the audits to keep the review system operating. In that case, the current system would continue without change, except for the lack of unhappy reviewers.
2. There would not be enough people left. The powers-that-be would then be motivated to reconsider the audit system and make some of the many improvements that have been suggested. That might attract some people back to reviewing, and would improve retention of new reviewers. Again, no more unhappy reviewers.

Comment: My question has nothing to do with anyone's happiness.

Comment: How is that being counter-productive? This answer solves the problem of having unhappy reviewers, but that has nothing to do with my question. I'm asking what can be done about review audits that users disagree with, not how to get rid of unhappy users.

Comment: If you tend to disagree with most all audits consistently, this absolutely applies, because clearly your goals and values as a reviewer are radically different from the rest of the community.  If you're largely happy and run across an occasional outlier that concerns you then ceasing to review is simply not a healthy response.

Comment: @Servy When I still did reviews, I passed almost all audits. The ones I "failed" were cases like a question that was reported closed for an incorrect reason, but should have been closed as a duplicate. I've tried upvoting constructive suggestions for improving audits, but nothing happens. The only lever I have is to not review.